# Sorting a list by a single particular element in a specified order

Tags: sorting

I have a list of lists -- a list of sublists -- that I wish to sort in a specified order. The following function, `sortBy2ndElement`, sorts a list of lists (`listToSort`) by the second element of each sublist, in the order specified by a score list (`scoreList`).

```
(* Function 'sortBy2ndElement': Sort the list 'listToSort' by the
second element (#[[2]]), in the order specified by the list 'scoreList'.

'scoreList' is of the form {{"C",1},{"A",2},{"B",3}} if the list
'listToSort' is to be sorted by the second element in the order "C", "A", "B". *)

sortBy2ndElement[listToSort_List, scoreList_List] := SortBy[listToSort,
   Switch[#[[2]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ Flatten[scoreList]]
     ] &
   ];
```

I wish to sort a list of lists by its second element (`#[[2]]`) in the order `"C"`, `"A"`, `"B"`, so my score list is as follows:

```
myScoreList = {{"C", 1}, {"A", 2}, {"B", 3}};
```

### Simple example (output is acceptable)

Now try sorting a test list, `myListToSort1`:

```
myListToSort1 = {
   {"Y", "A", "R2"},
   {"X", "B", "S2"},
   {"Z", "C", "T2"}
   };
sortBy2ndElement[myListToSort1, myScoreList]
```

> `{{"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"X", "B", "S2"}}`

So `myListToSort1` is sorted as desired.

### More complicated example (output is unacceptable)

But now suppose the list has multiple sublists containing each of the elements in the score list.  For example:

```
myListToSort2 = {
   {"Y", "A", "R2"},(* I wish to keep the third elements in the order given. *)
   {"Y", "A", "R1"},
   
   {"X", "B", "S2"},
   {"X", "B", "S1"},
   
   {"Z", "C", "T2"},
   {"Z", "C", "T1"}
   };
```

When I operate `sortBy2ndElement` on `myListToSort2`, I obtain the following:

> `{{"Z", "C", "T1"}, {"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Y", "A", "R1"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"},  {"X", "B", "S1"}, {"X", "B", "S2"}}`

The function has sorted the **second-element** sublists in the order `"C"`, `"A"`, `"B"` as desired, but it has also sorted the ***third-element*** sublists into canonical order (i.e., `"T1"`, `"T2"`; `"R1"`, `"R2"`; and `"S1"`, `"S2"`).

### My question

I would like to modify the function `sortBy2ndElement` so that it *retains* the ordering of the ***third-element*** sublists given in the input.  So, instead of the above, I wish to obtain this output:

> `{"Z", "C", "T2"}, {{"Z", "C", "T1"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"Y", "A", "R1"},   {"X", "B", "S2"}, {"X", "B", "S1"}}`

***How do I do this?***  It seems the problem is with [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) sorting in canonical order.

Please know that I'm running a *very* old version of *Mathematica*, version 9.0.  If possible, I would like potential solutions to work on *Mathematica* 9.0.

Answer (score 9):

[`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html):

[image]

**1.** For a minimal change in OP's function, wrap the scoring function in a list, i.e., use `{Switch[...]&}`, in the second argument of `SortBy`:

```
sortBy2ndElementB[listToSort_List, scoreList_List] := 
 SortBy[listToSort, {Switch[#[[2]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ Flatten[scoreList]]] &}]

sortBy2ndElementB[myListToSort1, myScoreList]
```

> ```
> {{"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"X", "B", "S2"}}
> ```

```
sortBy2ndElementB[myListToSort2, myScoreList]
```

> ```
> {{"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Z", "C", "T1"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"Y", "A", "R1"},  
>  {"X", "B", "S2"}, {"X", "B", "S1"}}
> ```

**2.** Alternatively, use `{#[[2]] /. Rule @@@ myScoreList &}` as the second argument of `SortBy`:

```
SortBy[myListToSort1, {#[[2]] /. Rule @@@ myScoreList &}]
```

> ```
> {{"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"X", "B", "S2"}}
> ```

```
SortBy[myListToSort2, {#[[2]] /. Rule @@@ myScoreList &}]
```

> ```
> {{"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Z", "C", "T1"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"Y", "A","R1"}, 
> {"X", "B", "S2"}, {"X", "B", "S1"}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

`Gather` elements with the same second element first, then sort, then `Flatten`.  A minimal change to your code would be:

```
myListToSort2 = {{"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"Y", "A", "R1"}, {"X", "B", "S2"}, {"X", "B", "S1"}, {"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Z", "C", "T1"}};
myScoreList = {{"C", 1}, {"A", 2}, {"B", 3}};

SortBy[GatherBy[myListToSort2, #[[2]] &], Switch[#[[1, 2]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ Flatten[myScoreList]]] &]~Flatten~1
(* {{"Z", "C", "T2"}, {"Z", "C", "T1"}, {"Y", "A", "R2"}, {"Y", "A", "R1"}, {"X", "B", "S2"}, {"X", "B", "S1"}} *)
```